# SwiftUI `withAnimation` doesn't work with `inout` parameter

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm writing an inspector view mocking macOS Sidebar behavior in SwiftUI. It use `.transition(.move(edge: .trailing))` only when the whole view appear and disappear but doesn't when switching between inner views. Here's the demo.

[image: Inspector Behavior]

So I come up with following code. `Selection` is an enum representing views one-to-one which always starts with `case none`. `inspect()` method is used for change selection value and determining if using animation (remember I mentioned not to use animation when switching between inner views). I attach my full code at the end.

However, there'll never be any animation applied. How can I fix this?

If I use this more specific one that uses @State `selection` directly in `inspect()` method, the animation comes back, but cannot reuse the code if I have another Inspector, like `@State var selection2: Selection2`.

```
func inspect(to target: Selection) {
    if target.rawValue == 0 {
        withAnimation {
            selection = target
        }
    } else {
        if selection.rawValue == 0 {
            withAnimation {
                selection = target
            }
        } else {
            selection = target
        }
    }
}
```

Here comes my full code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    enum Selection: Int {
        case none
        case view1
        case view2
        case view3
    }
    
    @State var selection: Selection = .none
    
    func inspect<Selection: RawRepresentable<Int>>(_ selection: inout Selection, to target: Selection) {
        if target.rawValue == 0 {
            withAnimation {
                selection = target
            }
        } else {
            if selection.rawValue == 0 {
                withAnimation {
                    selection = target
                }
            } else {
                selection = target
            }
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            VStack {
                Button("None") {
                    inspect(&selection, to: .none)
                }
                Button("View 1") {
                    inspect(&selection, to: .view1)
                }
                Button("View 2") {
                    inspect(&selection, to: .view2)
                }
                Button("View 3") {
                    inspect(&selection, to: .view3)
                }
            }
            
            Group {
                if selection.rawValue == 1 {
                    Text("Hello 1")
                } else if selection.rawValue == 2 {
                    Text("Hello 2")
                } else if selection.rawValue == 3 {
                    Text("Hello 3")
                }
            }
            .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
        }
        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks a bit to complicated so I have simplified it and if I understood what you want to do correctly it also behaves as expected.

First I made use of the @State property directly in the `inspect` function thus removing the need to pass it as an argument and also generics is not needed here

```
func inspect(to target: Selection) {
    if target == .none {
        withAnimation {
            selection = target
        }
    } else {
        if selection == .none {
            withAnimation {
                selection = target
            }
        } else {
            selection = target
        }
    }
}
```

As seen above I am using the enum cases directly and not any raw value, as a matter of fact I removed that from the enum

```
enum Selection {
    case none
    case view1
    case view2
    case view3
}
```

and also change the code in the `Group` because of this

```
Group {
    if selection == .view1 {
        Text("Hello 1")
    } else if selection == .view2 {
        Text("Hello 2")
    } else if selection == .view3 {
        Text("Hello 3")
    }
}
```

Overall I think this makes the code cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: Because I want to use the `inspector()` logic for different Inspector enums (maybe I will have more than one inspector), so I couldn’t tell it works that using of the @State property directly in the inspect function.

Comment: I mean it can work for `selection: Selection` in this example. But if I have another state value `selection2: Selection2`, this function cannot been reused.

Comment: I don't really see what is so reusable to this since the function is so tightly connected to the view, sure we could change the enum and `inspect()` to use a raw value of type Int again but it would still require every enum you use to have a case with the raw value 0.